# param is missing or the value is empty:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to include a select list in my get request to the new_item_path The problem I'm having is it doesn't send the intended resource object, in this case :item back to the controller so item_params doesn't have item prepended to it

param is missing or the value is empty: item

```
<%= form_tag new_item_path(@item), :method => :get do %>

      <div class="field">
            <%= select_tag(:item_type, options_for_select(Item::ITEM_TYPES)) %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "New item" %>
      </div>

<% end %>
```

Comment: you mean this doesn't show ? `Item::ITEM_TYPES` ? Can you show me how you defined it in the model Item?

Comment: That's not what I mean Your example is a direct call to the model anyway I mean `params.require(:item)...` cannot be satisfied because the item object isn't being prepdended to item_params

Comment: Maybe show your params as submitted

Comment: show me code of the new method then, I guess you make the wrong permitted params. In this case `params[:item_type]` is ok then

Comment: Started GET "/items/new?item_type=Pez+dispenser&commit=New+item&utf8=%E2%9C%93" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-10-26 22:41:53 -0400
Processing by ItemsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"item_type"=>"Pez dispenser", "commit"=>"New item", "utf8"=>"✓"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: item):

Comment: def new
     @item = Item.new(item_params)
     @item_item_properties=@item.item_item_properties.build
      end

Comment: However, I don't use @item_item_properties anywhere, seems like I've defined it in the controller for nothing

Comment: I guess you misunderstand how to use the form and how to render the form for the first time

Comment: Can't I use item_params in the new action?

Comment: which version of rails are you using by the way?

Comment: I posted the answer below, tell me if it works? @fugeeohu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code in select_tag to
`<%= select_tag("item[item_type]", options_for_select(Item::ITEM_TYPES)) %>`